# Need help in writing Powershell script to change the Extension Attribute 1 value to ‘Staff’ in AD Users and Computers >> OU >> Distributions groups?

Tags: powershell

Need help in writing Powershell script to change the Extension Attribute 1 value to ‘Staff’ in AD Users and Computers >> OU >> Distributions groups?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time and start with taking the [Tour]. You should further on read [Ask] and ho to create a [MCVE] before you proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser) and [Set-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser). Read the documentation to learn more but the general syntax is:

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -searchbase 'OU=SomeOU,DC=Contoso,DC=COM' | Set-ADUser -Replace @{extensionAttribute1='Staff'} -whatif
```

This gets all users `-filter *` in the specified OU `-searchbase 'OU=SomeOU,DC=Contoso,DC=COM'` sends them through the pipeline `|` to `set-aduser` where the extensionAttribute1 is set to Staff `-Replace @{extensionAttribute1='Staff'}`. Finally `-whatif` is used to show what would happen without actually affecting any changes. This helps ensure your syntax is correct.